# Setting Time Zone per session with Multi-Tenant Hibernate and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, timezone, multi-tenant

I am using Hibernate 5 and Spring Framework 5 to add multi-tenancy (DB per tenant) to our existing application. I have successfully implemented the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` and `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and the DB connections are working fine. The next step is setting the Time Zone per tenant.

I want to set the Tenant's time zone on the session and it seems the best way to do that would be to implement a custom `SessionFactory` and override the `openSession()` method. My custom method would create a new session as before, but also set the `jdbcTimeZone()` as appropriate.

Is this a valid approach or is there a better way to ensure all sessions have the time zone set before the are used?

I read through [this Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-hibernate-session-configuration) many times but it has not helped.

I was hoping Hibernate provided a "TenantTimeZoneResolver", but I have found no such thing.

This is what I have attempted so far:
Created a custom session factory that overrides `openSession()` and provides the desired time zone. This example just uses a hard-coded value, but will eventually grab the TZ from the tenant context.

```
public class CustomSessionFactory extends SessionFactoryImpl {
    public CustomSessionFactory(MetadataImplementor metadata, SessionFactoryOptions options, QueryPlanCache.QueryPlanCreator queryPlanCacheFunction) {
        super(metadata, options, queryPlanCacheFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public Session openSession() {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Detroit");

        return this.withOptions().jdbcTimeZone(tz).openSession();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is how to instantiate my `CustomSessionFactory`? Where do I get the MetadataImplementer, SessionFactoryOptions, and QueryPlanCreator?